# How to return which exact keywords were found in a PDF

Tags: python, regex

I want to see the exact words that were found in a PDF file once a search is complete. Right now the output that's given for a found term is the entire list of kTerm's followed by "found".

```
import PyPDF2 as PDF #import pdf module 
import re

  p = PDF.PdfFileReader("819001e.pdf")

  # get number of pages
  NumPages = p.getNumPages()

  #define keyterms; David, Final, End, Score, Birthday, Hello Ben

  kTerm = 'Electromagnetic|electromagnetic|Electronic|'


  #extract text and do the search
  for i in range(0, NumPages):
    PageObj = p.getPage(i)
    print("Looking through page " + str(i))
    Text = PageObj.extractText()
    Result = re.search(kTerm,Text)

    if Result:
         print(f"{kTerm} found")
    else:
         print("0")
```

This is the current output:

```
Looking through page 0
0
Looking through page 1
0
Looking through page 2
0
Looking through page 3
0
Looking through page 4
Electromagnetic|electromagnetic|Electronic| Electronic Warfare|electronic|electronic warfare|Chief Information Officer|CIO|Defense Acquisition Management System found
Looking through page 5
0
Looking through page 6
0
Looking through page 7
0
Looking through page 8
```

The output I want:

```
Looking through page 0
0
Looking through page 1
0
Looking through page 2
Defense Acquisition Management System found
```

Comment: My actual question is how do I return the exact words from kTerm are found in the pdf.

Comment: Im asking why the exact words that were found in the PDF are not returned in the output.My output solely returns the entire kTerm list followed by "found". It does not output the specific words that were found in the document

Comment: `kTerm = r'Electromagnetic\|electromagnetic\|Electronic\|.+\|([a-zA-Z\s]+)$'` , then `print(Result.group(1))` or smt like this

Answer (score 0):

Going by the documentation for re.search() [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), what you want is likely to be:

```
if Result:
    print(f"{Result.group(0)} found")
```

Comment: `group(0)` return the full match not the last part, `Defense Acquisition Management System found`